# 301 Redirect of URLS ending with a trailing slash

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I am a bit confusued about 301 Redirects.

A regular Redirect like this works totally fine

```
Redirect 301 /old.html http://www.domain.de/new.html
```

But how do I redirect URLs like this:

```
Redirect 301 /old/subfolder/XY/1/ http://www.domain.com/new1.php
Redirect 301 /old/subfolder/XY/2/ http://www.domain.com/new2.php
```

Because the schema mentionied above doesn't seem to work in this case.
Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: You're missing where you want to redirect to. `Redirect 301 /old/subfolder/XY/1/ http://www.domain.com/new2.html`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I changed my question, because this is exactly whats not working for me and I habe no clue why.

Comment: I'm assuming `/old/subfolder/XY/1/` is a directory? Do you want to redirect any requests to that directory to the new url? Or is there a landing page there (like `index.php` or `index.html`) that you want to redirect?

Comment: Hi, Ben, well in fact I can't tell exactly because it used to be a CMS System so I assume its not really a folder but a single page. Thanks for your reply